# Editing Google Drive Documents Directly

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, cloud, google-drive-api

I want to find out if the following is possible to do:
I currently have a webpage that lists all the google drive files I have access to, some of these are standard microsoft office files (.docx, .xlsx).

What I would like to do is when I click on one of these link, rather than have it download first then open, open it up directly in the standard editor for the filetype... so when I click on a docx file, it should open in Microsoft word, or when I click on the xlsx file, it should open up in Microsoft excel... so I can edit the document and when I click save, it saves my updates directly in google drive document. 
It might not always be microsoft office, ... if I log into the site using a mac, then when I click the link, i would expect it to open in openoffice...

Is this even possible? (if not, what other provider can I use to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Box has the capability to edit a file directly from their web page (and even lock it from other user's updates).

When you save it, it is saved directly to the Box cloud without having to mess around with local folders. Really nice.

IMO, this is a huge miss for Google Drive. I get it - they want you to convert your office docs to their format, but in Corp. America, that won't fly.

Of course Google will say get Google Sync, then you can double-click from your local sync folder and edit/save. Ok, but then what is the point of the cloud if you have download it to your laptop anyway? Offline, but that's risky to if someone else updates the doc while you were offline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will checkout Box.  Agreed that google missed out on it, they could even have sold it as a seperate service.  As the client uses google business for the company's email service, so authentication would've been easy.